# How to let robot_pose_ekf recieve IMU data from gazebo

Tags: imu, gazebo, navigation, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm using robot_pose_ekf with gazebo simulator.

Now, I've encountered with a problem that the /robot_pose_ekf only takes in /odom while the IMU data is not transferred.

To be more detailed, /gazebo published IMU data as topic: /mobile_base/sensors/imu_data [sensor_msgs/Imu]. However, /robot_pose_ekf didn't subscribe this topic, instead it listen to /imu_data which has no publisher! I feel it so strange and cannot understand it at all.

Can anyone tell me how to let /robot_pose_ekf subscribe the right topic from /gazebo? FYI, in the launch file of /robot_pose_ekf I tuned "odom_used" "imu_used" to "true" and "vo_used" to "false".

Any hints are welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Clack

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229315/how-to-let-robot_pose_ekf-recieve-imu-data-from-gazebo/) by [Clack](https://answers.ros.org/users/25357/clack/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2016-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

did you try to remap  /mobile_base/sensors/imu_data  -> /robot_pose_ekf ?

http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap

---

Originally posted by [Captcha](https://answers.ros.org/users/14366/captcha/) with karma: 61 on 2016-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Clack](https://answers.ros.org/users/25357/clack/) on 2016-03-17**:
It works! Thank you so much!

But to be more precise, the command to be added in robot_pose_ekf.launch should be:

```
<remap from=”imu_data” to=”mobile_base/sensors/imu_data”/>
```

:)